# Cannot access field customDimensions on a value with type ARRAY<STRUCT<hitNumber INT64, time INT64, hour INT64, ...>> at [1:104]

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud

I am new to google bigquery.I am trying to get the data from one of google bigquery dataset but getting below error [screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv4JI.png)

SQL query:

```
SELECT  h.value
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`,
UNNEST(hits.customDimensions) AS h
LIMIT 10;
```

Please let me know what mistake,I'm doing here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`hits` is an array. You can't access elements of an array directly; you need to unnest the array in order to produce a sequence of elements that you can reference. You may have meant to unnest both `hits` and `customDimensions` instead:

```
SELECT cd.value
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`,
UNNEST(hits) AS h,
UNNEST(h.customDimensions) AS cd
LIMIT 10;
```

The `customDimensions` array is empty for every row in the `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` table, though, so you will receive an empty result set for this query. In practice, if you have non-empty `customDimensions` in your own table, running a similar query against it would produce results.

Comment: ,I have marked the answer accepted but as I have reputation below 15, It will not show publicly.                                                                                      
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: @sam: accepting the answer (i.e. the green checkmark) is different from upvoting. And in any case, now you have enough rep to upvote too. :)